# Выравнять шапку таблицы в Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-table

Привет друзья, подскажите, не могу выровнять шапку таблицы со стилем в Bootstrap 4
`<thead class="thead-default">` 
в общем такая таблица:

```
<div class="text-lg-center">
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-default">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Имя</th>
                <th>Фамилия</th>
                <th>Номер телефона</th>                        
                <th>IQ</th>
                <th>Город</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>123</th>
                <th>123</th>
                <th>123</th>
                <th>123</th>
                <th>123</th>
                <th>123</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Как сделать что бы данные в шапке и в теле были по центру?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый вечер. Используйте класс `text-center`. Более подробный ответ можно найти по ссылке http://bootstrap-3.ru/css.php#grid вкладка - типография, раздел - выравнивание классов. В вашем примере `<th class ="text-center">ID</th>`. Так выравнивание сработает

Comment: Я его использовал, не помогло

Comment: поправил ответ на более подробный

Comment: Помогло, спасибо большое

Comment: @АндрейСуворов Всегда пожалуйста!